# Moving from Magento Community to Professional

Tags: php, magento

A client of mine would like to build their ecommerce website using the community (free) edition of Magento.

But in the future they "may want to use customer store credits and upgrade to the professional (paid) version then".

Is this even possible? 
Can you just upgrade and bolt on the professional version to the community version? 
OR would this mean starting the website from scratch again from within the professional package?
[Magento Versions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/compare)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure not to change any of the core files, and you'll be mostly fine. Expect to spend some time upgrading your template once you make this switch.

Answer (score 1):

If you build your customization in proper way it is very easy to upgrade CE to PE.

Answer (score 0):

If they want to switch to Professional only because of the store credits maybe you should advise them to just install an extension that provides that functionality. Or, better yet, code that for them :)